# How do I clear and reload the the data in dataTable()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

On load I am loading the data in the data Table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: currentSelectedPolicyResults.data,
        scrollY: '50vh',
        columns: [
            { title: "TaskId", data: "TaskId" },
            { title: "Task Description", data: "Task Description" },
            { title: "Status.", data: "Status" }
        ]
    });
    setClick();
});
```

How do I clear the data from current table? Then I want to load updated JSON into the same table, how do I do this?

I can clear the data using:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.clear().draw();
```

But when I try to load updated JSON it's showing this error

`DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.`

***Reload Function : `table.rows.add(UpdatedJSON.data);`***

Answer (score 1):

Try this
$('#importListTable').DataTable().fnClearTable();

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use an 'innerHTML =' to load your data into. Then just run your script again and it will clear it and place updated data there. I know this is short but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your data once in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#yourtable').DataTable();
});
```

after ajax call 
you just need to use it like this

```
$.ajax({
                url: baseURL + 'YourURL',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(Data),//if any
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (json) {

                    $('#yourtable').DataTable().clear().draw();
                    $('#yourtable').DataTable().rows.add(json); // Add new data
                    $('#yourtable').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw(); // Redraw the DataTable

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occured!!!");
                }
            });
```

Comment: I am not using ajax. I am using a JSON object "currentSelectedPolicyResults.data"

Comment: $('#yourtable').DataTable().rows.add(UpdatedJSON.data);
after clear().draw()

Answer (score 0):

One of my friend help me to find a way,

var table = $('#example').DataTable();
To Clear Table:

```
table.clear().draw();
```

To Reload:

```
table.rows.add(updatedJSON).draw();
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Add `"destroy": true` when initialising the datatable first.
Then, try using `table.clear().draw();` when reinitialising the datatable with new data.